# Why the script is adding same object with same tag twice to the List and different positions?

Tags: unity, c#

The script should let the player shoot bullets either manual or automatic by pressing the mouse left button for single shot and right mouse button for automatic fire.

The problems :

- In my scene i have one object tagged with "Fire Point" but in the method GatherAllChilds it's finding two objects and in fact it's the same object tagged with "Fire Point" he is adding the object to the List firePoints.
- It should not adding twice the "Fire Point" object but even if it does adding it twice why they are both have a different positions ? shouldn't they have the same position ? I used a break point and when the variable 'i' is 5 it's adding the "Fire Point" twice in a row same number 5 object and yet they are in a different positions.

The result is when the player is shooting there is two places the bullets are coming from instead one.
The script Instantiate two clones of the bullet prefab in the method LaunchProjectile lines 70 to 73.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;
 
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;
 
    private List<Transform> firePoints = new List<Transform>();
    private Animator anim;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        GatherAllChilds(transform);
 
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
 
    public void Update()
    {
        if (overAllSlowdown == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = slowdownAll;
        }
 
        if (firePoints.Count > 0 && anim != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < firePoints.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false && IKControl.handRaised)
                {
                    LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]);
                }
                else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true)
                {
                    automaticFire = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2") && IKControl.handRaised)
                    {
                        automaticFire = true;
                    }
                    if (automaticFire == true && IKControl.handRaised)
                    {
                        LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    private void LaunchProjectile(Transform firePoint)
    {
        Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
            bulletPrefab,
            firePoint.position,
            firePoint.rotation);
 
        projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);
 
        if (bulletsSlowDown == true)
        {
            if (projectileInstance != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AddDrag(maxDrag, bulletSpeed, projectileInstance));
            }
        }
 
        if ((automaticFire == true || automaticFire == false) && bulletsSlowDown == false)
        {
            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            projectileInstance.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }
 
    IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float bulletSpeed, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        if (rb != null)
        {
            float current_drag = 0;
 
            while (current_drag < maxDrag)
            {
                current_drag += Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed;
                rb.drag = current_drag;
                yield return null;
            }
 
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.drag = 0;
 
            rb.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            rb.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }
 
    private void GatherAllChilds(Transform parent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; i++)
        {
            if (parent.GetChild(i).name == "Player")
            {
                anim = parent.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Animator>();
            }
 
            if (parent.GetChild(i).tag == "Fire Point")
            {
                firePoints.Add(parent.GetChild(i));
            }
            GatherAllChilds(parent.GetChild(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And the class bullet destruction

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class BulletDestruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float destructionTime;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Init()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DestroyBullet());
    }
 
    IEnumerator DestroyBullet()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(destructionTime);
 
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Screenshot image showing the Fire Point object found twice with different positions

[image: Positions and twice]

Comment: side tip: no need for WaitForSeconds in your case, just add the destruction time into `destroy` like this: `Destroy(gameObject, destructiontime)` and it'll destroys the object after the given time

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of code here that is not related to the GatherAllChilds method you want help with. Please delete this to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example containing *only* the code required to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project. This helps get accurate answers faster, by cutting down on distractions.